# How to query specific rows per date and per user?

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
user | date
 1   | 2016-08-10
 1   | 2016-09-10
 1   | 2016-10-10
 2   | 2016-08-15
 2   | 2016-08-18
 2   | 2016-08-19
```

What I want to do here is to get the specific user for every date. For example, I want to get the users where **date >= 2016-08-12**. My expected result would be:

```
user | date
 1   | 2016-09-10
 2   | 2016-08-15
```

I would note that these dates are actual date and different users have different dates with them, thus in this example, the values of date2 for the two users will be different.

Will anyone be able to help me formulate a proper query for this?

Thank you

Comment: Need valid data to understand thoroughly. Otherwise many questions would arise like `Is date3 less than date2? ...`

Comment: @1000111 updated the question

Comment: Please tell me why the other dates which are greater than `2016-08-12` didn't come up in the output

Comment: @1000111 that's what I want to happen to don't include the other dates only retrieve one per user

Comment: Take a look at the `GROUP BY` function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query.

```
SELECT 
T.user,
MIN(T.date) AS min_date
FROM your_table T
WHERE T.date >= '2016-08-12'
GROUP BY T.user;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f57c0/1/0)

**Note:** This query picks the first date that is greater than the input date for each user.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE date > '2016-08-12 00:00:00'
```

with the restriction that the `date` column will be declared as `Date` type